# Select rows having max column value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, filter

I have an array of ActiveRecord of table Person (:id, :name, :city_id, :work_id, :date). For eg :

```
[<Person id: 4, name: John, city_id: 10, work_id: 1, date: 2015-10-10>,
  <Person id: 5, name: Jack, city_id: 11, work_id: 2, date: 2015-10-08>,
  <Person id: 8, name: John, city_id: 10, work_id: 2, date: 2015-10-11>,
  <Person id: 9, name: John, city_id: 10, work_id: 3, date: 2015-10-11>,]
```

For a particular person, I want the rows with the maximum date. So, for Jack, I'll get row with id = 5. For John, I'll get the rows with id = [8,9] as the date is maximum for these rows. I can't figure out an efficient way to to this in Rails. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `maximum` class method of rails.

Try this:

Person.find_all_by_date(self.maximum('date'))

See some details [here.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/maximum)

Comment: I don't want the value of maximum date. I want all the rows of each distinct person with maximum date in his all rows.

Comment: I want to operate on an array of ActiveRecord i.e. an array containing rows of table Person.

Comment: Why do you want to use an array? Can you put a little more information about your problem? I'm assuming that you want to know all the last works performed by a given person in a particular city?

Comment: I have a table Person which tells that the person John works in city_id 10 on work_id 1 on this day. I have another table Tenure(:id, :name, :work_id, :start_date, :end_date) which tells that a person with this name works on this work_id from start_date to end_date. A nil end_date means that he is still working on that work. I want to fetch all the Person rows who are currently working. So I want to fetch the Person rows of the last date for each person.