# Compare two dates in Case statement in sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to compare two dates in rails in a Case statement in sql Select statement.

```
School.select("CASE (#{holiday_date} > holidays.start_date)...")...
```

holiday_date is a parameter in my function and holidays.start_date is a column in holidays table. But, this gives me the following error :

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer > date
```

Why is Rails understanding the variable as an integer.

Comment: What is the return type of your function ??? and specify exact data type of `holidays.start_date`

Comment: An array of ActiveRecord rows.

Comment: Just show sample value in `#{holiday_date}` and `holidays.start_date`

Comment: That looks like a PostgreSQL error - not a ruby error.

Comment: @ReggieB Definitely it is

Comment: holiday_date = Sun, 08 Nov 2015
holidays.start_date = Tue, 10 Nov 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your param to date before compare it to your column value. In your case you should try:

```
School.select("CASE (to_date('#{holiday_date}', 'DD Mon YYYY') > holidays.start_date)...")
```

Where 'DD Mon YYYY' is the date format and you can see the options [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html).

Comment: holiday_date is already in Date format. I am passing it to the function as Date.parse(time.to_s)

Comment: Yes, but your database is understanding it as integer.

Comment: I got this after using to_date -> PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid value "11-" for "Mon"
DETAIL:  The given value did not match any of the allowed values for this field.

Comment: To use your month as a number , you should use MM in the date format instead of Mon. If your using the american format, your should use 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

Comment: Can you also look into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728063/select-rows-having-max-column-value-in-rails/33728134